# NHAPI ZPI Segment

Tags: hl7, hapi, nhapi

We are planning to use NHAPI in our application as a PILOT run. I am in the process of verifying whether the current message can be parsed using NHAPI.

So we got a segment named  "*ZPI – Additional Prescription Information Segment*". Since I believe there are no segment defined to parse it, is it possible to use **Zxx** segment?

Regards,

Raaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at how the following unit test parses a message with a custom Z segment:

https://github.com/duaneedwards/nHapi/blob/master/NHapi20/NHapi.NUnit/CustomZSegmentTest.cs

You'll have to poke around the code / classes to see how it works and there will be a bit of setup, this won't just work with the message you have as is.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I have written the custom segment

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is possible

```
 ORM_O01 or = new ORM_O01 ();

 ORM_O01_ORDER order = or.getORDER ();

 order.getMessage().addNonstandardSegment ("ZDS");

 Terser t = new Terser (or); t.set ("ZDS-1-1", "1223"); t.set
 ("ZDS-2-1", "RIS71");


 _ormmsg.addNonstandardSegment("ZDS");

 Terser terser = new Terser(_ormmsg);

 terser.Set("ZDS-1", "1");

 terser.Set("ZDS-2", "2");

 terser.Set("ZDS-3", "3");
```